# Want this animation back to previous positions

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am making an animation, designed with CSS and actions are done with JQUERY.
This is working fine, now if user clicks button again then this animation should have positions it had previously.

**Here is my code-**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
$(".t").click(function(){
$("p").animate({left:'350px',top:'350px'},1000);
$("p").animate({left:'600px'},1000);
$("p").animate({top:'348px',opacity:'0.8'},500);

});});
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".t").click(function(){

$(".u").animate({right:'350px',top:'260px'},1000);
$(".u").animate({left:'500px'},500);
});});
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".t").click(function(){
$("#q").animate({top:'250px',opacity:'0.4'},1000);
$("#q").animate({left:'500px'},500);
$("#q").animate({top:'460px'},500);
$("#q").animate({left:'500'},500);

});
});
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".t").click(function(){
$("#s").animate({top:'350px',left:'400px'},500);
$("#s").animate({top:'360px'},500);
});

});
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".t").click(function(){
$("#c").animate({top:'360px',left:'500px',opacity:'0.5'},500);
});
});


</script>
</head>
<body>


<input type="submit" style="width:80px;font-size:2em;color:white;height:80px;box-shadow:0px -0px 5px skyblue; border-radius:100%;font-weight:bold;font-family:calibri;text-shadow: -1px -1px 0px #111111;background-color:#98bf22;cursor:pointer;" value="Press" class="t"></input>

<span id="s" style="background:red;width:100px;height:100px;position:absolute;box-shadow:0px 0px 5px 1px white;top:22%;left:20%;border-top-left-radius:100%;border-bottom-left-radius:100%;"></span>
<p style="background:#777641;border-top-right-radius:100%;border-bottom-right-radius:100%;width:100px;height:100px;position:absolute;top:21.3%;left:60%;box-shadow:0px 0px 5px 2px white;"></p>
<span class="u" style="background:#2198bf;border-top-right-radius:100%;border-top-left-radius:100%;width:100px;height:100px;position:absolute;top:14%;left:40%;box-shadow:0px 0px 5px 3px white;"></span>
<span id="q" style="background:blue;width:100px;border-bottom-left-radius:100%;border-bottom-right-radius:100%;height:100px;position:absolute;top:30%;left:40%;box-shadow:0px 0px 5px 2px white;"></span>
<span id="c" style="background:yellow;width:100px;height:100px;position:absolute;top:22%;left:40%;box-shadow:0px 0px 5px 1px white;"></span>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is fiddle-
http://jsfiddle.net/stackmanoz/vbkBQ/9/

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/bstakes/hzFTg/#base fiddle. Hope it helps

Comment: @ManojKumar, you're going to have to be more specific: do you want the button to repeat the exact-same animations in the exact same way, from the very start?  Do you want it to go back an animation frame, every time it's pressed?  Do you want it to play backwards?

Comment: @Norguard , I want toggle like action, when animation is complete and you clicked button again you get same as it was. Yes i want it repeating animation every time i click button

Comment: look at this fiddle it may help you http://jsfiddle.net/ipsjolly/RhsgR/2/

Comment: @Rahul, your animation is not working

Answer (score 0):

This script does what you are expecting

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
$(".t").click(function(){
    if($("p").css("left") == '60%'){  //check if p exist in the default position
        $("p").animate({left:'350px',top:'350px'},1000);
        $("p").animate({left:'600px'},1000);
        $("p").animate({top:'348px',opacity:'0.8'},500);
    }else{ //if p is animated and move to new position reset is position
        alert("here");
        $("p").css('top','21.3%');
        $("p").css('left','60%');
    }
});});
```

This script checks if the P element is animated and moved to a new position, if moved it resets it, else it animates that element. This similar check can be done for other elements in your fiddle too.

Comment: I don't want to give else positions. What i want is if animation is completed then it should automatically move to it's previous state on second click. Is there any way?

Comment: the fiddle  [link](http://jsfiddle.net/bstakes/hzFTg/#base) posted by @usman in your quesion does that.